# "on Wi-Fi", "by Wi-Fi", "through Wi-Fi" or "via Wi-Fi"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which one of the following sentences is correct.

> I can only watch it **on** Wi-Fi.
>
> I can only watch it **by** Wi-Fi.
>
> I can only watch it **through** Wi-Fi.
>
> I can only watch it **via** Wi-Fi.

Comment: It's a relatively new context, so usage hasn't settled down yet. All your alternatives are at least "acceptable" (as would be, for example, ***...using** Wi-Fi*), and it's really just a matter of personal opinion / preference which to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that "I can only watch it by Wi-Fi." isn't normal usage, but the other three are all fine.

Since I work in IT, the first one grates a little, and 'via' is better, but for everday usage the reverse is probably true.